# Archive manager started instead of executing a shell-script

Tags: nautilus, scripts

When I double click on a .sh (the file is executable) file in Nautilus the archive manager is started instead of executing the script. How can I make Nautilus show the dialog (execute/edit/...) again?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the permission of the file to executable using terminal.

Open terminal.
Navigate to the directory where your file located (using `cd`).
Change the permissions using:

```
chmod +x filename.sh
```

and then try

```
./filename.sh
```

or try executing it using

```
sh filename.sh
```

**Reasons :**

It may be because, your default text editor(gedit) may not be available, or in properties window, on the open with tab, the default one is archive manager. In this case change open with using gedit or install gedit (if not available).
Or the file is meant for 32 bit, and you may be executing in 64 bit OS (vice versa).

Comment: if it's a shell script, it's irrelevant what architecture he's using. shell scripts aren't compiled, so they are architecture-independent.

Comment: The file has the executable-flag. I changed the "open with" to gedit, but now the script is opened in gedit instead of executing it. I can launch the script using ./filename.sh, but it should also be possible with nautilus.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this one of two ways.

**Way Number One: GUI**

Right click the file

Select the permissions tab

Check the box that says "Execute file as a program"

---

**Way Number Two: Terminal**

The first way does not always work for me so i use this one instead

Open the terminal with Ctrl + Alt + T

Navigate to the directory your file is in using `cd` (ex. if your file is in your Downloads folder you would use the command `cd ~/Downloads`

Finally execute the command `./name_of_file_here.sh`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I checked the first way, the checkbox is already checked, but although I can't execute the script... Currently I'm executing the scripts with the terminal, but I don't know why ubuntu isn't showing this dialog any more...